# react bootstrap navbar can show the dropdown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, navbar, bootstrap-5

i am new to react and i find that when i copy the bootstrap navbar and use the dropdown.There are nothing happen.but everything works fine except that.I dont know where is the problem
my layout:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './layout.css'
class Layout extends Component {
    state = {  } 
    render() { 
        return (
            <nav style={{ "backgroundColor": "#e3f2fd" }} className="navbar navbar-expand-lg  ">
            <div className="container-fluid  ">
                <a className="navbar-brand text-muted" href="/">STH News</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div  className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li  className="nav-item">
                            <a  className="nav-link active text-muted " aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" >
                                News
                            </a>
                            <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form className="d-flex" role="search">
                        <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>);
    }
}
 
export default Layout;
```

Comment: I am finding it hard to understand your problem. What exactly is not working?

Comment: The drop down is not working.But i have try used the react-bootstrap and it works.Thx for your reply